# Taking data from JSON into google sheets using specific info

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm so bad at titles and I don't know the technical terms, sorry about that.

I've managed to take the data from [here](https://universalis.app/api/Ultros/36105), but how do I make it only pull data from `"hq":true`? This is what I have so far:

`=ImportJSON("https://universalis.app/api/Ultros/36105","/listings/pricePerUnit","noHeaders")`

I assume I can't just /"hq":true because the hq and pricePerUnit is in the same...row? If that makes sense. So do I comma it? /pricePerUnit,"hq":true? I only want it to pull the hq data to my google sheet. Is this possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of the property of `listings` from the URL of `https://universalis.app/api/Ultros/36105`. At that time, you want to retrieve the values with `"hq":true`.

In your situation, how about directly preparing a Google Apps Script for retrieving the values? When this is reflected in a script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and save the script. And, when you use this script, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE("https://universalis.app/api/Ultros/36105")` to a cell.

```js
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  const v = obj.listings.filter(({hq}) => hq === true);
  const header = Object.keys(v[0]);
  return [header, ...v.map(o => header.map(h => Array.isArray(o[h]) ? o[h].join(",") : o[h]))];
}
```

#### Result:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- When you want to change the order of columns, please replace `Object.keys(v[0])` with the array including the header values you want to use.
- If you don't want to add the header, please modify `return [header, ...v.map(o => header.map(h => Array.isArray(o[h]) ? o[h].join(",") : o[h]))];` to `return v.map(o => header.map(h => Array.isArray(o[h]) ? o[h].join(",") : o[h]));`
- This sample script is for `https://universalis.app/api/Ultros/36105` of your question. So when you change the URL, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.
- From `/listings/pricePerUnit`, when you want to retrieve the value of `pricePerUnit` when `"hq":true`, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    function SAMPLE(url) {
      const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      const obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
      return obj.listings.filter(({hq}) => hq === true).map(({pricePerUnit}) => [pricePerUnit]);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)